# APNS for .net Framework 2

Tags: c#, iphone, json, apple-push-notifications

I am wishing to use Apple Push Notifications generated using calls to a web service which has a target framework version of 2.0.

I am aware that System.Runtime.Serialization.Json is not supported until 3.5 but I'm not wishing to move.

With that in mind, I cant use 'apns-sharp' " http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/ " 
which is an open source libary that I could have embedded into my web service application.

So, without upgrading my .net Framework, what would you guys suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APNS-Sharp is, in fact, .Net Framework 2.0 compatible. in the past you had to remove the unnecessary .Net 3.5 assembly references and using statements, my [commit](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp/commit/5c897ddd41fa74529c2bc3c70eff3172e030701a) took care of that.

Download the [source code](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp), change the target framework to .Net 2.0 and build a .Net 2.0 compatible dll. (You also need to reference Newtonsoft.Json.dll for .Net 2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried JSON.NET?  It's a NuGet package too so easy to install.  You can use it for the JSON serialization.

Comment: a little later on the reply but thanks any way - as per previous comment i just updated the framework - ill upvote you for the answer though as perfectly valid!

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own notification service with the .net framework 2, helped by apns sharp. It's not very difficult.

Comment: gave up thinking of a quick term solution, so just updated the framework. thanks for your reply :)